# How to parse csv file with tab delimited values in Pandas (with tab delimited values within row elements)

Tags: pandas

How do you read a tab delimited file that has a pipe '|' in some of the columns.

When I try to read it using `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')`, pandas interprets the string with the '|' file as a separate column and I get a parse error. Am I missing something?

Example Dataset:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3


1|2|3

4|5|6

7|a||9
```

Pandas interprets the third row as having four columns because the row element 'a|' has a '|' in it. Instead, I would like Pandas to read 'a|' as belonging to Col2. Is there a better library within Python to do this or a correct way to parse this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='[|^]+')` to consider any number of consecutive characters of | as one separator.